# Chrome takes positve values for onclick event generated through Enter key, while Firefox and IE do not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose you have a link

```
<a onclick="clickme(event);" href="javascript:void(0);" align="center">click me<a>
```

The listener is:

```
function clickme(event) {
    var evt = event || window.event;
    console.log("clientX = " + evt.clientX + " & clientY= " + evt.clientY);
}
```

Chrome output: clientX = 0 & clientY= 0

Firefox/ IE output: clientX = 0 & clientY= -105

How do you resolve this issue?

I need the position of the link where I create a pop-up menu.
(0,0) is a valid position for a pop-up menu. But not when the pop-up menu is supposed to be in the center of the page. Chrome will still take the position as (0,0).

Comment: Try `evt.pageX` and `evt.pageY`

Comment: @Tushar, nope. same result. I also tried `evt.layerX` and `evt.layerY`. Same.

Comment: These properties are only well defined if it's a mouse event, not a keyboard event.